# 'jQuery' is undefined error in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

```
    <head>
    <meta name="description" content="Directory" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sitename.com/javascripts/toggle.js" language="javascript"></script>

    </head>
```

this is the error showing in IE 7. I haven't checked in IE8 and 6.

```
Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://sitename.com/javascripts/toogle.js
```

This is code of external javascript

```
(function($) {

     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.divhide').hide();
                  $('#ShowFields').show();
$('.DirectoryLink') .addClass('plus');
$('#DirectoryLink') .addClass('minus');
        $('.DirectoryTextLink').click(function(){
              $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('minus');
                return false;
   });
});


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not enough information. Show us all the scripts.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the wrapper function surrounding your code - never seen that before - is there are reason for the first function($) and the trailing (jQuery)?  the toggle doesn't execute if just placed in the regular $(document).ready function?

Comment: @DeaconDesperado: It's a self-invoking anonymous function which calls itself with the `jQuery` object as parameter. That pattern just makes sure the `$` is bound to `jQuery` no matter what.

Comment: </head> tag missing? In the above code you don't include the "/", is this a typo?

Comment: @DeaconDesperado Sometimes there are conflicts with other libraries that use the $ variable. Reassigning $ to jQuery in a new function scope is a nice way around that while still using $.

Comment: @Charlie Brown - thanks . it was a typo

Comment: @Deacon we can do it in three different methods 
`1)`$(function(){...}); `2)`$(document.ready(function(){...}); `3)`(function(){...})();

Comment: @Daniel et al - ah interesting thanks - so it's somewhat like an inverse of .noConflict()?

Comment: Get rid of the language attribute in your script tag. Not sure if it will fix it, but it's deprecated anyways so you don't need it.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: See my revised answer and hopefully that should work (although I have no idea why it would only happen in IE).

Comment: Is there any issue with using https and http with IE? Try removing the secure https from the script uri and just use plain http. IE throws up a lot of crazy warnings when cross site security is used.

Answer (score 3):

Did you include the jQuery file before toogle.js?

EDIT 1: Also: Get rid of the language attribute in your script tag. Not sure if it will fix it, but it's deprecated anyways so you don't need it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sitename.com/javascripts/toggle.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

Instead use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sitename.com/javascripts/toggle.js"></script>
```

EDIT 2: In toogle.js add this line before the self invoking function:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Even though you're reassigning $ in the function, you may still need to call the `noConflict` method.

From: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: does it effect our script if we include 'language' attribute in script tag ?

Comment: @Samurai Jack: I doubt it, but it's typically considered bad practice to use deprecated attributes or elements. Although most deprecated features still work, it doesn't mean it will always work.

@metal-gear-solid: See my new edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because one script is **http** and the other is **https**, this will cause a security issue with IE when the parent page is on a https. If your parent page is on a https you must have everything on https, including images and scripts.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: Try it anyways. Internet Explorer has a lot of "security features" that will randomly break stuff.

Comment: firefox is more permissive when it comes to https, ie will just ignore everything that's not https and depending on the security configuration it will not even ask